# Multiple animations in CSS - Only repeats the seconds animation

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I want to run two animations parallel, whereas the second animation has an delay of 1s.

The code below runs perfectly in the initial iteration, however, the first animation `dash01` is only executed once although I set it to run infinitely.

```css
#Vector_42 {
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    animation-name: dash01, dash01Rev;
    animation-duration: 5s, 5s;
    animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite, infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear, linear;
    animation-direction: forwards, forwards;
}

@keyframes dash01 {
    0% { stroke: #0066cc; stroke-dashoffset: 5; }
    10%, 100% { stroke-dashoffset: 15; }
}

@keyframes dash01Rev {
    0% { stroke: #0066cc; stroke-dashoffset: -5; }
    10%, 100% { stroke-dashoffset: -15; }
}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Azrion/hzrbfj34/1/

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you removed all those prefixes. You can add them later if you have to support old browsers but for simplicity sake I'd remove them for the question

Comment: both are animating the same properties so only one could run at once

Comment: @Dominik I made it more readable now :) sorry for that

Comment: No need to be sorry :) And as @TemaniAfif said, you can't animate the same property twice. You have to find another way to animate this svg :(

Comment: @TemaniAfif then why does both animations run at the same time for the very first iteration? I assume there must be a way that it can repeat this infinitely

Comment: because of the delay, the first time only one is running then the other one start after 1s of delay and will take the lead (the other will do nothing)

Comment: @TemaniAfif that makes sense thank you! :) 
Do you know an approach to keep this delay of 1s infinitely and not only once?

Comment: I think you need to find a way to write only one animation. In that animation you can have an empty slot (this will be your delay) and then the states you want and you repeat it.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do. If you want that line to go back and forth indefinitely then just create an animation that goes back and forth and repeat that. I'm not sure what the outcome of the animation should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Temani Afif's suggestion:

Simply do everything in one animation. You need to compute or estimate how much a 1s delay is and implement it that way:

```css
@keyframes dash01{
    0% { stroke: #0066cc; stroke-dashoffset: 5; } // Start going forward
    10% { stroke-dashoffset: 15; } // Continue same way
    10.1% { stroke-dashoffset: 15; } // Still continue
    20% { stroke-dashoffset: 15; } // Still continue
    20.1% { stroke-dashoffset: -5; } // Set reverse way
    30% { stroke-dashoffset: -15; } // Go reverse now
    100% { stroke-dashoffset: -15; } // Keep going reverse :D
}
```